# NET8 Entity Framework Core check if the model is compatible with the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I'm creating a project in `NET8` and `Entity Framework Core` using a database first approach, because the database already exists and I have to use it. The database is managed by a third party. I can't clean or delete the database.

I have created the model using scaffolding and now it is working. My problem is detect if there are some changes in the database and then I can update my model.

In the old version of Entity Framework there was a command for it

```
bool isCompatible = context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true);
```

but now this command is not available any more. I saw a few posts:

- [How to check if database schema matches Entity Framework schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089448/how-to-check-if-database-schema-matches-entity-framework-schema)
- [How to use Entity Framework code-first with a newer database model version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265672/how-to-use-entity-framework-code-first-with-a-newer-database-model-version)
- [Does an equivalent to Database.CompatibleWithModel(bool) exist in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240689/does-an-equivalent-to-database-compatiblewithmodelbool-exist-in-ef-core)

All the posts are old and referring to old version of the Entity Framework. So, it is not usable with the new version. Also, I saw a NuGet package called [EfCore.TestSupport](https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCore.TestSupport) but I think it is using an old version of the framework.

Using a database first approach, is there a way to check if the created model is compatible con the current structure of the database?

Comment: No native method for db-first. You'll heave to rely on third-party products or (better) ask the schema owners to inform you of schema changes ahead of time. BTW, this `CompatibleWithModel` wouldn't have helped you either. It only works with migrations.

Comment: As a workaround, what about to perform a `dbcontext.Set<M>().Take(1)` for each model and catch exceptions?

Comment: @daniherrera it will not guarantee that models are compatible.  For example it will not catch cases when new non-nullable column without default value was added.

Answer (score 1):

I believe CompatibleWithModel was removed in EF 7.  I use the following:

```
 var database = context.DbContext.Database;
 int pendingMigrations = database.GetPendingMigrations();

 bool hasMigrations = pendingMigrations > 0;
```

If there are migrations, then the model is not compatible.